# Как удалить значение из Listview значения которых хранятся в firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Я знаю что надо как то получить autoID но не понимаю как, и как возможно сделать так чтобы при долгом нажатии на значение в списке можно было ее удалить из firebase

Answer (score 1):

@SmileXD!

Ваш вопрос является комплексным, и требует разделения.

**1. Вопрос про [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView)**

В нынешнее время Вам не следует использовать ListView в Android приложениях, т.к. уже давно доступен более эффективный виджет - [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).
Google в первом же абзаце об этом и говорит

> Displays a vertically-scrollable collection of views, where each view is positioned immediatelybelow the previous view in the list. For a more modern, flexible, and performant approach to displaying lists, use RecyclerView

**2. Как удалить из списка по долгому нажатию**

Так как я надеюсь, что Вы пересмотрите свое решение и замените `ListView` в свом экране на `RecyclerView`, то для обработки длительного нажатия Вам нужно во `ViewHolder`'е установить `setOnLongClickListener()` на контейнер, который содердит в себе элемент списка.

*шаг 1:* определить interface, который будет отвечать за передачу действия куда нужно. Пусть будет так
// код на `Kotlin`

```
interface MyItemClickListener {
    fun onItemLongClick(entity: Entity)
}
```

*шаг 2:* во `Fragment`'e или `Activity` нужно реслизовать этот interface
*шаг 3:* в `MyCustomAdapter` передать ссылку класса Вашего `Fragment``Activity`. В конструктор можно.

```
private val adapter: MyCustomAdapter by lazy { MyCustomAdapter(this) }
```

*шаг 4:* В адаптере эту ссылку нужно будет передавать в каждый элемент списка Вашего `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` класса в методе `onBindViewHolder(...)`.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val entity = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(entity, clickListener)
}
```

*шаг 5:* Непосредственно в классе `MyViewHolder` будет следующее

```
class MyViewHolder(
    private val binding: ItemCardElementBinding
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(entity: MyEntity, clickListener: MyItemClickListener ) {
        // код инициализации виджетов, какая-то логика вывода данных в ячейку списка
        binding.containerView.setOnLongClickListener { clickListener.onItemLongClick(entity) }
    }
}
```

*шаг 6:* В реализации метода `onItemLongClick(entity: MyEntity) {}` в `Fragment` \ `Activity` нужно отправить запрос на удаление в Ваш `Presenter` \ `ViewModel`, которые далее по правильной цепочке (опущено, чтобы не растягивать ответ) передадут вызов в репозиторий `Firebase` (`Firebase RealTime Database` \ `Firebase Firestore`). К примеру, он будет называться `FirebaseDBImpl`.

*шаг 7:* Этот репозиторий отправит запрос на сервер `Firebase` с помощью методов API Firebase. К примеру, так:

- Cloud Firestore Doc: [читать](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#kotlin+ktx)
- Firebase RT database на SO: [читать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37393676/5521569)

*шаг 8:* Асинхронно передать результат удаления из БД обратно в `Presenter` \ `UseCase -> ViewModel`, которые так же анхронно вызовят метод у `Fragment` \ `Activity`. Последние должны отправить запрос на обновление состояния Вашего адаптера для `RecyclerView`:

- используя DiffUtils
- используя удаление элемента из коллекции адаптера, а потом вызвывать `notifyItemRemoved()`.

Как Вы могли заметить, я постарался дать Вам ответ, в котором есть общие шаги. Конкретную же реализацию Вам нужно будет написать самостоятельно, т.к. в Вашем вопросе мало деталей.

Задавайте вопрсосы в комментариях ниже, я постараюсь дать Вам ответы и\или дополнить текущий.

Удачи! ;-)